# generics method for closing resource files

Tags: java, generics

I have cursors, inputstreams, outputstreams that instead of doing .close() to each one, I call a method on them that closes them.

I tried something like that :

```
private static void closeResource ( Object<T>  item )
    {
        try
        {
            if ( item != null )
            {
                item.close();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work.. Object is not generic.

Comment: Few problems with this code. First, `Object` does not have a type parameter, so `Object<T>` is invalid syntax (unless you defined your own `Object` type, in which case, show us that class). Next, you don't declare the generic type `T` anywhere. Third, the `Object` class from the JDK does not have a `close()` method, so you're going to have to be more detailed with what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Object` is not a generic type so you can't use `Object<T>`.
2. The `Object` class has no `close` method defined in it.

The generics-oriented solution is to define a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) with a type parameter bound to the `Closeable` interface which declares the `close` method:

```
private static <T extends Closeable> void closeResource ( T  item )
{
    try
    {
        if ( item != null )
        {
            item.close();
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to be generic method, actually :)

Comment: Yes just highlighting the correct way based on the title.

Comment: Thank you!
But in order to do that I have to implement AutoCloseable if I'm correct, and it requires API 19 in Android (while my min defined is 9).
Is there any way to overcome that issue?

Comment: @BVtp [`Closeable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) is there since JDK1.5.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.
However my app crashes now..
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented

Comment: @BVtp Please post this in another question.

Answer (score 2):

All the streaming classes (`InputStream`, `OutputStream` and friends), implement the [`Closable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) interface (which actually *defines* the `.close()` method they all implement), so you can do:

```
private static void closeResource (Closable item ) { .. }
```

Comment: Isn't `AutoCloseable` the parent of Closeable?

Comment: Yes, `AutoClosable` is the super-interface of `Closable`.